# Entering and leaving the UK on the day of visa expiry

Tags: visas, uk

I will be entering the UK in the morning and leaving in the evening of my multiple entry visa expiry date as I have a 12 hr layover in LHR. Will I be granted entry if I have my itinerary showing that I'm leaving on that same day?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I wouldn't say 'of course'.  I'm aware of cases when people with valid visas were not granted entry at LHR.  I would say, most likely the OP will be ok, but it all depends on the border control officer's perception of risk of you overstaying.

Comment: Let's put it another way: You have a valid visa, you are using it before it expires, why are you worried?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The asker is presumably worried for exactly the reasons Aleks has set out. You repeatedly making the same claim that there's nothing to worry about isn't helpful.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "Of course" is probably wrong. But what I really want is clarification. Despite their wide discretion, immigration officers really aren't generally arbitrary and capricious about their decisions. There's nothing given here to indicate that the OP _won't_ be granted leave to enter, so I'm asking for that additional information.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of validity of your visa, it is valid till the midnight of the date of expiry; but I am sure you already know this.

So, speaking from practical terms - there is nothing illegal about your itinerary. However, as we all know - visas are not guarantees of entry into a country. The immigration officer has to be convinced that you are not going to violate or have not violated previously the terms of your visa.

The final decision lay in the hands of the immigration officer; despite the practical calculations.

Therefore, I would try to explain the purpose of your stay in the UK (as you normally would), and further explain that you have a return itinerary.

In some cases, the officers can grant you a special permission / stamp which allows you to enter the country on a limited basis. They might do this, just to make sure you don't end up violating your visa terms - say in case you get stuck in traffic and aren't able to clear immigration in time; but this is usually done in emergency situations.